# Set a Previously Created Ajax JSON Object to a Variable in a Different File?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know how I can set a previously created Ajax JSON object to a variable in an unrelated file?  Is there a jQuery function that does this?

EDIT: My form functions file renders by sending an ajax request.  After that request is returned with a JSON object I use those values in the form functions file.  Now though I need to use those values in the JSON object in a different JavaScript file that gets rendered after the ajax call occurs.

Comment: i guess you have to explain better...

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin - I added a more detailed description.

Comment: All scripts inserted in a page share the same global scope. The variable will be available if it's accessible. I'm not promoting use of global variables, just saying that different inserted scripts live in the same space.

Comment: you can use global variable. not recommended but if you have to, you can.

Comment: @Jason You have to pass the JSON object as a parameter to the function in you different JavaScipt file. Globals is a bad practice ^